# Excel VBA - Find string in column and insert data in that row

Tags: string, excel, vba, find, range

I'm trying to figure out how to use excel to scan a table for a specific number, say the number 50 for the sake of the example. When my code finds the number 50 in the table I want to set that row where 50 is and insert some user defined text in to the right of it. I then have all sorts of VLOOKUPs, MATCH and IFERROR functions already set up that will work on from there. But I'm having a bit of trouble at the moment. I'm using a Userform to insert the data. The context is a Student Enrolment system, the student ID will be present and when the user selects a course that course ID will automatically be assigned to said student.

I've used similar code to assign data entry to the next free row. But I want this to assign the data entry to a specific row, not just the next free one. The code I used previously is as follows.

```
Dim LR As Integer, Master As Worksheet Set Master =
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Student")

LR = 6

If LR = 6 And Cells(LR, "A").Value = "" Then 
    LR = LR 
Else 
    LR = LR + 1
    If Cells(LR, "A").Value = "" Then 
    Else 
        Do Until Cells(LR, "A").Value = "" 
            LR = LR + 1 
        Loop 
    End If 
End If

Master.Cells(LR, "A").Value = (Me.txtID) 
Master.Cells(LR, "B").Value =(Me.txtFore) 
Master.Cells(LR, "C").Value = (Me.txtSur)
Master.Cells(LR, "D").Value = (Me.txtAddress) 
Master.Cells(LR, "E").Value = (Me.cmbSex)

Unload UserForm1
```

As you can see, that code sucessfully assigns the data entry to the next available row and then closes the form using the LR (Last Row) loop. I found that worked quite well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*EDIT*

Here's the finished code all working, thanks to Paul!

```
Dim FR As Integer, Course As Worksheet, CourseCode, StudentID As String
Set Course = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Course")
Set Enrol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enrolment")
StudentID = txtID
CourseCode = cmbCourse
FR = 6
Dim lRow As Long



If FR = 6 And Course.Cells(FR, "B").Value = CourseCode Then
FR = FR
Else
    FR = FR + 1
    If Course.Cells(FR, "B").Value = CourseCode Then
    Else
        Do Until Course.Cells(FR, "B").Value = CourseCode
        FR = FR + 1
        Loop
    End If
End If

lRow = Enrol.Range("A6:A45").Find(StudentID).Row

Select Case CourseCode
Case "Animal Care"
CourseCode = "9841"
Case "Animation"
CourseCode = "3320"
Case "Art"
CourseCode = "6387"
Case "Biology"
CourseCode = "4685"
Case "Business Studies"
CourseCode = "5879"
Case "Calculus"
CourseCode = "4123"
Case "Chemistry"
CourseCode = "1586"
Case "Computing"
CourseCode = "3669"
Case "Dance"
CourseCode = "4521"
Case "Design and Tech"
CourseCode = "5478"
Case "Drama"
CourseCode = "5678"
Case "Engineering"
CourseCode = "6321"
Case "English Language"
CourseCode = "4768"
Case "English Literature"
CourseCode = "3908"
Case "Fashion Design"
CourseCode = "2477"
Case "Film Making"
CourseCode = "4489"
Case "French"
CourseCode = "2548"
Case "Functional Skills"
CourseCode = "2685"
Case "Geography"
CourseCode = "8874"
Case "German"
CourseCode = "9512"
Case "Graphic Design"
CourseCode = "5232"
Case "History"
CourseCode = "4895"
Case "Italian"
CourseCode = "6578"
Case "Japenese"
CourseCode = "5988"
Case "Korean"
CourseCode = "9874"
Case "Latin"
CourseCode = "3478"
Case "Law"
CourseCode = "2321"
Case "Mathmatics"
CourseCode = "9458"
Case "Media Studies"
CourseCode = "1589"
Case "Modern Languages"
CourseCode = "5612"
Case "Nursing"
CourseCode = "2003"
Case "Photography"
CourseCode = "2001"
Case "Physical Education"
CourseCode = "8496"
Case "Physics"
CourseCode = "8534"
Case "Religious Studies"
CourseCode = "2320"
Case "Social Studies"
CourseCode = "2301"
Case "Spanish"
CourseCode = "6217"
Case "Statistics"
CourseCode = "4895"
Case "Textiles"
CourseCode = "2240"
Case "Travel and Tourism"
CourseCode = "5698"
End Select

Enrol.Cells(lRow, "E").Value = (CourseCode)

Unload UserForm3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding it difficult to understand what exactly you are looking for. If you want to find the row that contains a value you can use the Find function

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Course.Range("A1:A1000").Find(StudentID).Row
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! That was really helpful and I've now managed to get it to work. I used the Find function and it worked perfectly! I'll post the finished code in the question above for others to see!